# Problem facing while creating a laravel project with composer

Tags: php, laravel, git, composer-php

I am facing this error while creating a new project in laravel.

My command is -

> laravel new project-name

And the error is

````
- Installing laravel/laravel (v10.0.5): Cloning 9ae75b58a1
        Install of laravel/laravel failed

In Git.php line 471:

  Failed to clone https://github.com/laravel/laravel.git via https, ssh protocols, aborting.

  - https://github.com/laravel/laravel.git
    Cloning into 'C:\Users\Dell\Desktop\ecommerce-app\ecom'...
    fatal: the remote end hung up unexpectedly
    fatal: early EOF
    fatal: index-pack failed

  - git@github.com:laravel/laravel.git
    Cloning into 'C:\Users\Dell\Desktop\ecommerce-app\ecom'...
    Host key verification failed.
    fatal: Could not read from remote repository.
    ```
  How to resolve the error?
````

Answer (score 1):

Try following ways:

```
composer clear-cache
laravel new project-name
```

And:

```
composer self-update
laravel new project-name
```